# How to make non-clickable App Icon on Action Bar like YouTube App in android

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I want to add non clickable App Icon on Action Bar like YouTube app have app icon on Top-Left of screen.Currently App Icon on Action behave like button.

Please see to know about app icon:

http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html

Comment: 1. What have you tried 2

Comment: 1. What have you tried 2. By default the icon is not click able. Just use .getActionbar().set logo(resid) to set a logo.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. Code is crashing with NoSuchMethodFoundException. I am using API Level 12 device.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for `getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false);` for appCompat. If you aren't using appCompat, then just `getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false)` assuming your activity is extending `ActionBarActivity`.